# Helm chart fails with "nil pointer evaluating interface {}" when trying to evaluate a missing nested key

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

I am writing a Helm 3 library chart and would like to create a YAML with default values. However, when trying to set a default value for a **nested** key that does not exist, Helm fails with the following error message:

`nil pointer evaluating interface {}`

Say I have this snippet in my Kubernetes object:

```golang
{{- if eq (.Values.deployment.scale.type | default "static") "static" }}
  replicas: {{ default "3" .Values.deployment.scale.replicas }}
{{- end }}
```

If `.Values.deployment.scale` is defined, the template will render fine and the value of `replicas` will be 3 even if `.Values.deployment.scale.replicas` is not defined.

However, if one of the parent keys is not defined, Helm will fail with the error message above. For example if `values.yaml` is the following:

```yaml
# values.yaml
deployment:
  not_scale: {}
```

The render will fail with: `nil pointer evaluating interface {}.scale`

How is it possible to set a default value for a nested key, even if its parent keys are undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to solve this using step-by-step evaluation of the hierarchy and using `default dict` to assign an empty map if the key does not exist. It both works and looks better.

Example:

```golang
{{ $deployment := default dict .Values.deployment }}
{{ $scale      := default dict $deployment.scale }}
{{- if eq ($scale.type | default "static") "static" }}
  replicas: {{ default "3" $scale.replicas }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think, you can set default for that case. You need to pre-check if `scale` field exists. For that, you can use [`hasKey` function from sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/bd7cb37b66a3bf86016d09188a371c36e5a63f21/docs/dicts.md):

```
{{- if hasKey .Values.deployment "scale" }}
{{- if eq (.Values.deployment.scale.type | default "static") "static" }}
replicas: {{ default "3" .Values.deployment.scale.replicas }}
{{- end }}
{{- else }}
replicas: 3
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the code accessing `.Values` was wrapped inside a `with ... end` block. In this case the current context no longer has a variable called `.Values`. The solution is to reference the global Values object with `$.Values`.

From https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/ :

> However, there is one variable that is always global - $ - this variable will always point to the root context. This can be very useful when you are looping in a range ...