# Default value in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a configmap yaml that needs to be executed if a particular value is set to true.
This is the config map yaml def

```
{{ if (.Values.telemetry.create) }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: telemetry-allowlist
data:
  metrics.json: |
    {
...
```

Now in some cases users forget to add this value
`.Values.telemetry.create`

This causes the entire setup to fail with the error

```
at <.Values.telemetry.create>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.create
```

Wondering how to add default values so that it defaults to false if the value is not present

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm chart fails with "nil pointer evaluating interface {}" when trying to evaluate a missing nested key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154736/helm-chart-fails-with-nil-pointer-evaluating-interface-when-trying-to-evalu)

Comment: You can assign `{{ $telemetry := .Values.telemetry | default dict }}` and then test on `{{ $telemetry.create }}`.  That will substitute an empty dictionary for the nil value and avoid the error.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid `telemetry` being empty, you need to add additional judgments.

According to the [helm document](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/), when the object is empty, the if statement judges to return false.

A pipeline is evaluated as false if the value is:

- a boolean false
- a numeric zero
- an empty string
- a nil (empty or null)
- an empty collection (map, slice, tuple, dict, array)

```yaml
{{ if .Values.telemetry }}
{{ if .Values.telemetry.create }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: telemetry-allowlist
data:
  metrics.json: |
    {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `telemetry.create` to `false` in your default `values.yaml` file.

```yaml
...
telemetry:
  create: false
...
```

So even if users miss setting the `telemetry.create` value, the helm will render from the default `values.yaml` file and you won't get the nil pointer error.